How to delegate an Azure DNS subdomain to a DNS Service that is not Azure DNS?
Current setup:
Azure DNS, authoritative for parent.com [name obfuscated]
Requirement:
Create a child zone called "child.parent.com" where the authority is NOT Azure DNS.
Problem:
When I create the child zone in Azure DNS, it automatically creates read-only NS records that point to the parent. In other words, it seems to be following the rule "once you're in Azure DNS, all child zones must also use Azure DNS as their authority".
I have tried deleting the NS records in the parent that point to the child and re-creating them to point to the external DNS provider NS servers. The GUI lets me do this. But, when propogating, the "conflict" in NS records meant that some External resolvers picked up the new NS records and some did not. In fact, some seemed to "flip flop" between deciding Azure DNS and the external DNS were authoritative - even after a week.
I have read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/delegate-subdomain
I refer to the following sentences:

"To delegate an Azure DNS subdomain, the parent public domain must first be delegated to Azure DNS" - Check. The parent IS in Azure DNS.
"Delegate a subdomain, step 6" states "These are the Azure DNS nameservers that are authoritative for the subdomain (child zone)." This is precicely the problem. Azure DNS is kind of trapping me into using Azure DNS nameservers.
"Manual entry of NS records (optional)" states "specify each of the nameserver entries that are listed in the subdomain (child) zone". Precicely the problem again. The NS servers in the subdomain (child) zone are also hard coded to Azure DNS. In other words, even creating the subdomain manually forces me to point the child to Azure DNS.

How do I create a child zone that is completely nothing to do with Azure DNS at all if the parent is in Azure DNS? Or, is there a rule that once the parent is in Azure DNS, all child zones must also be in Azure DNS?
